# Sqlalchemy When should literal_column or be used instead of bindparam?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

On the face of it, it seems that `bindparam` should generally be used to eliminate SQL injection. However, in what situations would it necessitate using `literal_column` instead of `bindparam` - and what measures should be taken to prevent SQL injection?

Answer (score 2):

`literal_column` is intended to be used as, well, a literal name for a column, not as a parameter (which is a value), because column names cannot be parameterized (it's part of the query itself). You should generally not be using `literal_column` to put a **value** in a query, only column names. If you are accepting user input for column names, you should whitelist what those names are.

One exception is that sometimes you want to output some really complex expression not directly supported by SQLAlchemy, and `literal_column` basically allows you to put freeform text in a query. In these cases, you should ensure that user-supplied parts of the expression (i.e. values) are still passed via bind params.